# Freeing memory across threads

Tags: c, pthreads, dynamic-memory-allocation

Is it a bad practice to free memory across threads? Such that a thread allocates memory and, after exiting, passes the pointer to the main thread to free the memory. I feel like the answer is yes but I'm just wondering.

The purpose of this in my code is so that the main thread can do some other stuff with the memory before it gets freed. There's plenty of workarounds, in my case, which I'm totally fine with using. But having a thread return void * to a block of memory can, in my case, make the code pretty convenient.

EDIT: I know there are no technical faults in doing this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not wrong for a thread to pass control of memory it has allocated to another thread.  For example, in a producer/consumer model, it would be very reasonable for the producer thread to allocate memory for whatever it is that it produces, and then hand control over that memory to the consumer thread for the consumer thread to use and release.

Comment: at 207k, I'd definitely take that advice haha

Comment: Treat 207k as a symptom of dementia — a deranged addiction to SO.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer because it's the only post that answers the question in the first sentence.

Comment: +1 to that comment because I think it applies to me too. At this point the only use I can find for rep is to throw around wild bounties; perhaps I should go throw them on other people's interesting questions that don't yet have good answers...

Answer (score 6):

It's not "bad practice" as long as it makes sense to your data flow model, and particular to the requirements your program has on object lifetimes, but it can incur costs. Many modern allocators use thread-local arenas, where allocating and freeing an object in the same thread incurs no synchronization penalty, but freeing it in a different thread forces synchronization or incurs other costs. I would not change your design for this reason unless it's a major bottleneck, but with this implementation-detail in mind you could also consider other designs, such as having the thread store its output in a buffer provided by the parent thread in the argument to the thread start function.

Comment: If someone can provide it, I request more info about the scenario where memory allocated from a thread-local arena is deallocated is a different thread (that doesn't own the arena).  What are strategies for handling this with the least performance hit?

Answer (score 2):

All threads share a common heap. It doesn't matter which thread allocates or frees the memory, as long as the other threads are done using the memory when it gets freed.

Comment: As https://stackoverflow.com/users/379897/r-github-stop-helping-ice 's answer indicates, some popular allocators use a mix of per-thread memory pools, along with the process-wide pool.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic memory usage comes with a responsibility that you are in complete control of it.  It is the user’s responsibility to explicitly manage the lifetime of the dynamically allocated object and ensure its deallocation once the expected lifetime of the object ends. There is nothing wrong in dynamically allocated memory blocks used across different threads. All the threads in the same process share the same heap area. The only care that one needs to take care is that the object lifetimes are clearly well defined and scoped.